# Creating a custom GUID while inserting the post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, customization, custom-post-type

Ok. Here's the problem. 
I am creating 2 posts in here. First one is parent post and second one is a attachment post.I want to create a custom guid while inserting the parent post. e.g.

guid => http://localhost/music/?post_type=pdf&p=1548

I tried inserting the wp_insert_post first and then updating it with the update post function but it didn't work. Can you help me out in here because I am stuck and I am unable to sort,also another related question.
Can you get the current insert id while inserting the post?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use raw sql:

```
global $wpdb;
$updateguid = $wpdb->get_results("UPDATE wp_posts SET guid ='what you want' WHERE ID ='inserted-id'");
```